# Toggling annotation on and off in matplotlib

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python script that uses matplotlib. The idea is that when the user runs the script, an interactive window pops up in which they can toggle certain plots on and off with the CheckButtons that matplotlib provides. I managed to figure out how to change the visibility of the plots themselves, however, I am struggling to do the same for the annotation. For the lines I have the following code:

```
def plotsetlines(lines,toggle):
    """ plot vertical, labeled lines """
    x = []
    lmin = 4
    lmax = 6
    for name in lines:
        x.append(lines[name])
        plt.annotate(s=name, xy=(lines[name], lmax), xytext=(lines[name], lmax+1.1), rotation=90,size='large', visible=toggle)
    print x
    return plt.vlines(x, lmin, lmax, lw=2,visible=toggle)
```

Here lines is a dictionary of the form:

```
lines1 = {"a":115.27, "b":115.0, "c":112.0}
```

and toggle is a boolean. Once this function has been called, I can change the visibility of the lines as follows:

```
lns1 = plotsetlines(lines1,True)
lns1.set_visible(not lns1.get_visible())
```

The problem is, I have no idea how I can do the same thing for my annotations easily. I know that the Annotate object has the get/set_visible methods as well, but the function I wrote doesn't return the annotations in the same way that it returns my lines, so I'm not sure what to call the methods on. Any suggestions and ideas are welcome.

Also, since this is my first question posted here, please let me know if you have suggestions about the layout/wording etc. of the question itself. Thanks!

Comment: `plt.annotate`/`ax.annotate` returns an artist that you can use similarly to your lines.  It has `set_visible` and `get_visible` methods just like the `Line2D` instance that you're currently calling `set_visible` on.

Comment: Glad to help! You'll need to return both objects. E.g. `return line, anno`

Comment: @JoeKington Thank you! I'll try that!

Comment: @JoeKington Your suggestion worked! Could you submit your solution as an answer so I can accept it?